# Getting error " Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am seeing following  using `mocha` and `chai` library for test case.
`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

here is `code` for testing handler for amazon lambda function.(for now , I am not using `super-test` npm module)

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CONFIG_DEV_MONGODB = require('../../config/config.dev').DB_CONNECTION_URL;


describe('get the foo', () => {

    let handler;
    before(() => {

        process.env.DEPLOYMENT_STAGE = 'test';
        process.env.DB_CONNECTION_URL = CONFIG_DEV_MONGODB;
        handler = require('./get');
    });

    after(() => {

        if (mongoose.connection) {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });

    it('validate getFeaturedProducts get request with storeid',function(done){
        //request has the sample data for event
        let request = require('../../test/fixtures/featureProductJSON');
        handler.getFeaturedProducts(request, {} , (error, result) => {

             expect(error).to.be.null;
             expect(result).to.be.not.null;
             done()
         })

    })
});
```

Here is the handler

```
module.exports.getFeaturedProducts = function (event, context, callback) {
    ..............
    .......
    mongoConnection.then( function() {
         return callback(null, 'test');
     }, function (error) {

        return return callback(true, null);;
    })
 }
```

can any one explain what is happening wne

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your tests are taking longer than Mocha expects them to take and timing out. By default, all callback functions timeout after 2000ms. You'll need to adjust the timeout of your test suite using [`this.timeout()`](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts).

You can specify this at the suite level in your `describe()`:

```
describe('get the foo', function () {
  this.timeout(10000) // all tests in this suite get 10 seconds before timeout

  // hooks & tests
})
```

You can specify this in a hook like `before()`:

```
describe('get the foo', function() {
    before(function() {
      this.timeout(10000) // 10 second timeout for setup
    })

    // tests
})
```

You can also do this at the test level in your `it()`

```
describe('get the foo', function () {
  it('validate getFeaturedProducts get request with storeid', function (done) {
    this.timeout(10000) // 10 second timeout only for this test

    // assertions
  })
})
```

Comment: `TypeError: this.timeout is not a function` is giving the below error.

Comment: You can't use arrow functions at all in Mocha. You'll need to use the plain old `function() {}` syntax. Arrow functions break the `this` binding when using Mocha. You can read more about it [here](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions). Notice how all my examples are using `function() {}` and not `() => {}`. If you look at the example in the link, you'll see the exact example they give is an Arrow Function breaking `this.timeout()`.

Comment: @made_in_india throughout that post and even in the final comentary, the recommendation is, arrow functions are highly discouraged. However, based on the commentary in that issue thread, it looks like you can chain `timeout()` to the `it()` BUT, only the `it()` via `it().timeout()`.

Answer (score 11):

Helped to add `.timeout(10000)` to the end of function `it()`

```
describe('Reverse String Test', () => {

 it('Compare first data',  async function () {
     try {
        await sql.connect(config);

        let request = await new sql.Request()
         .query('SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.valJob');
             console.log(request);
        await sql.close();

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

 }).timeout(10000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of prevent this situation. You just modify the `Mocha` default timeout `2000`ms to `10000`ms.
To add a `--timeout` flag on your `package.json` like:

```
"scripts": {
   // rest of your scripts
   "test": "mocha server/**/*.test.js --timeout 10000"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem faced me and i tried to fix it by several methods :
1- try to expand the mocha timeout more than 2 seconds by doing this

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --timeout 20000",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
    },
```

2- if it does not solve the problem ,ensure that you make export for the main server file it could be app.js or server.js or other you name it , that is the file that contain this lines of code

```
    app.listen(3000,(()=>{
        console.log("server is listen on port 3000") })
     module.exports = app;
```

3- if it didnt solve put the timeout inside the it block

```
    it("Should respond with 400 if there's an error on schema",async 
     function () {
        this.timeout(20000)
            let res = await request(app)
            .post("/users/signin")
            .send({
                "email": "ahmed22kjsdnkjdsbf@yahoo.com",
                "password":"1234"
            })
        expect(res.statusCode).equal(401,res.body.message);
```